# How do I dump the sphinx doctree to disk when troubleshooting custom directives?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am working on a custom directive and can't figure out what's going on. Is there a way to dump the whole doctree to disk in a human-readable format?

Comment: Using `make foo` will dump doctrees into your `_build/doctrees` directory.

Comment: I already have `build/doctrees` but they are in some kind of binary (pickled?) format.

Comment: There might be more information at https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/peps/pep-0258.html#docutils-package-structure or https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/peps/pep-0258.html#processing-model